# CKEditor & Skype button not visible

Tags: ckeditor

I have code for skype button and it is visible on user page but invisible in CKEditor. What to do to make it visible in CKEditor content?

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://secure.skypeassets.com/i/scom/js/skype-uri.js"></script>
<div id="SkypeButton_Call_fasdf_1">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Skype.ui({
            "name": "dropdown",
            "element": "SkypeButton_Call_fasdf_1",
            "participants": ["fasdf"],
            "imageSize": 24
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any javascript that you include in the CKEditor content won't be executed, so you'll have to create a plugin that detects that HTML and shows an icon for that code (and dialog to edit?)